# How to run a web browser in background on android?

Tags: c#, android

Is there an analogue of `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser()` for android development? I need to parse some data from a website, but I also need to run some JS code on it beforehand. How it can be done?

Comment: I've found a solution to me question in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357767/webview-how-to-run-even-when-app-is-in-background-closed-foreground-service-act